# My app crashes on startactivity intent in master flow detail / fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

My app keeps crashing on `startActivity` line. I am using mastedetail/fragmentsts here. I also tried using `getactivity()` instead of context . and `getactivity().finish` , but that didn't work either, it doesn't even reach to the next class it crashes on `startactivity(intent)`.

Althought the intent line points to the reserve.java file.

```
  if (mItem.id.equals("3")) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reserve, container, false);
            //((WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.item_detail)).loadUrl(mItem.item_url);
            context = rootView.getContext(); // Assign your rootView to context
            Button btDate = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnDate);
           btDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    //Pass the context and the Activity class you need to open from the Fragment Class, to the Intent
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, reserve.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                   // startActivity(new Intent(context, reserve.class));
                }
            });
        }
        return rootView;
```

**reserve.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content">

        <View android:layout_height="60dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="#b0c4de"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:padding="50dp"
            android:text="@string/txtTitle"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:typeface="serif" />
        <TextView />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <View android:layout_height="50dp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="@string/btnBig"
            android:textSize="36sp" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <View android:layout_height="60dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtReservation"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:textSize="36sp" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**reserve.java:**

```
public class reserve extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView reservations = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtReservation);
    Button btDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDate);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    DateFormat fntDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d = new 
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int 
monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            c.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            reservations.setText("Your Reservation is set for" + 
fntDate.format(c.getTime()));
        }
    };
        public View onCreateView(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            btDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    new DatePickerDialog(reserve.this, 
d,c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), 
c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
                }
            });
            return reservations;
        }
}
```

The Error after the startactivity works, it crashes in reserve.java on this line

```
TextView reservations = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtReservation);
```

the error log for this crash is:

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.gg.classicalindianmusictickets, PID:20130
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity 
    ComponentInfo 
     { 
     com.example.gg.classicalindianmusictickets/
    com.example.gg.classicalindianmusictickets.reserve}:
     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
    'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null 
    object reference
                      at 
    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2820)
                      at 
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3027)
                      at 
    android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(
       LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
                      at android.app.servertransaction.
    TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:101)
                      at android.app.servertransaction.
    TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:73)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage( 
    ActivityThread.java:1786)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main
   (ActivityThread.java:6656)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at 
    com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
    (RuntimeInit.java:438)
                      at 
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke 
    virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback 
    android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init 
     (AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:117)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>
```

[image: The rserve.java starts this blank page]

[image: I want it to do this on the same reserve.xml page]
[image: And display a txtview as such:]
updated reserve.java

```
 public class reserve extends AppCompatActivity {


      public View onCreateView(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final    TextView reservations = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtReservation);
            Button btDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDate);
          final  Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
         final   DateFormat fntDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
        final  DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
              @Override
              public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                  c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                  c.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                  c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                  reservations.setText("Your Reservation is set for" + fntDate.format(c.getTime()));
              }
          };

          btDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    new DatePickerDialog(reserve.this, d,c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
                }
            });
            return reservations;
        }
}
```

Comment: `reserve.class` here `reserve` is an Activity or Fragment?

Comment: Please provide the crash log with your question.

Comment: try context.startActivity(intent);

Comment: BTW, `reserve` is a terrible name for a class. See [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/).

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed Thankyou so much the app does not crash now , however  I am not able to do what i intened to , My reserve.java is used to select a date for the concert and display the result in in txtreservation which is all part of reserve.xml , but my reserve.java opens a new page .. I updated my question with the picture of that , I want the btnDate to allow the user to choose a date and display it in the same page..hate Fragments !erh!

Comment: In your way, you just start a new activity. That will open a new page. If you want to do this then you need to handle reserve design to current activity. Not starting the new activity.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is to get `Context` from view. Which is not correct to start the intent. If you are in `Fragment` class then simply the `getContext()` to get the context and the use the context for start intent.

```
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reserve, container, false);

  context = getContext();  
  Button btDate = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnDate);
  btDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, reserve.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

You need to add this line on `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity android:name=".reserve"/>
```

or if you add some details then use this

```
 <activity
        android:name=".reserve"
        android:label="@string/title_reserve" 
        android:parentActivityName=".reserve"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.gg.classicalindianmusic.reserve" />
    </activity>
```

This should be in `onCreateView`. Not on top.

```
TextView reservations = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtReservation);
Button btDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDate);
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Really appreciate your reply , but its still not working . I think the problem is in manifest file. here is my error log:

Comment: Please provide the crash log with your question.

Comment: If you missed to add Activity to manifest then please add first.

Comment: Please also share the `reserve` class codes. Is it actually an Activity?

Comment: @Rishika If `reserve` is an activity the just add this on manifest.xml `<activity
        android:name=".reserve"/>`. Hope this will solve this problem.

Comment: Hello , the startactivity is working now and it reaches to the reserve.java file , but it crashes inside the javafile , i added the details of the crash log above , thankyou so so much for your help , i really appreciate it

Comment: Thankyou so much the app does not crash now , however I am not able to do what i intened to , My reserve.java is used to select a date for the concert and display the result in in txtreservation which is all part of reserve.xml , but my reserve.java opens a new page .. I updated my question with the picture of that , I want the btnDate to allow the user to choose a date and display it in the same page..hate Fragments !erh! –